# How does type conversion works in JS?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I'm new to programming, and currently I learn JS. There's one thing about operators/type conversions that kind of confused me. Here are some practice examples that I tried:

`"4px" - 2`

//this returns **NaN** because this string can't be converted into number to do the arithmetic.

```
"2" * "3"
```

// this returns **6** because they can be converted into numbers.

```
" \t \n" - 2
```

// now this one is the one that I don't get it. The result is **2**. I thought this string can't be converted.

Please enlighten me on the last example, thanks!

Comment: In the last example the result is -2, not 2.

Comment: Oops, yeah you're right, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings that consist of all whitespace characters are converted to the number 0. It's [section 7.1.3.1 in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type).  A numeric literal can include leading or trailing spaces plus zero or more digits. If there are no digits, the value is 0.